# Understanding lack of compassion exhibited by Iranian experts in catastrophic situations

Tags: cognitive-psychology, communication, expertise

In recent catastrophic situations, there have been reports of Iranian experts displaying a lack of compassion towards ordinary people affected by these events. This raises questions about the underlying psychological factors contributing to this behavior, particularly in the context of the influence of Islamofascism.

I came across a post titled "The Role of Experts Outside of the Country in Influencing the Situation Inside the Country" (link: [post link](https://telegra.ph/The-Role-of-Experts-Outside-of-the-Country-in-Influencing-the-Situation-Inside-the-Country-08-29)) that explores the complexities and importance of external experts in shaping policies and decision-making processes.

I am interested in understanding the lack of compassion exhibited by Iranian experts in catastrophic situations, considering the influence of Islamofascism, and would like to know if there are any psychological theories or research that can shed light on this phenomenon.

Additionally, I am curious about effective ways to utilize the internet to document and address these actions.

By asking this question, I hope to engage with the Psychology & Neuroscience community to gather diverse perspectives, scholarly resources, and practical insights that can contribute to a better understanding of the lack of compassion exhibited by Iranian experts in catastrophic situations, considering the influence of Islamofascism.

Please provide any relevant context or background information that can help the community provide more informed and insightful answers.

(Note: This question was generated by ChatGPT. [ChatGPT website](https://www.phind.com/agent?cache=cllwiaymc000aky08mq2eet8n))

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.